# Eliminar consonantes de un array javascript

Tags: javascript

tengo este array:

```
arr = ["average", "exceptional", "amazing"];
```

y necesito que el output sea este:

```
newAarr = ["aeae", "eeioa", "aai"];
```

Como puedo eliminar las consonantes de cada palabra? He utilizado un forEach para entrar en cada elemento, luego habría que revisar las posiciones de cada uno si es una vocal o no, y en caso de ser consonante borrarla, finalmente volver a unir el string sin las consonantes, con join() supongo.

Siguiendo el código del compañero, una solución podría ser esta:

```
var a = ["average", "exceptional", "amazing"];

var b = [];

a.forEach(el => {
  
  let aux = "";
  
  for(let i=0;i<=el.length;i++) {
    if(el[i] == "a" || el[i] =="e" || el[i]=="i" || el[i]=="o" || el[i]=="u") {
    aux += el[i];
  }
 
  }
    
  b.push(aux);
})

console.log(b);
```

Quizá hay alguna manera en Regex para seleccionar todas las vocales y evitar tantos OR?

Aún así, la intención era resolverlo con métodos de los arrays, tipo map, slice i join, pero no he encontrado la forma.

Comment: podrias colocar el codigo de lo que as intentando hasta ahora?

Comment: Quería intentarlo con map, pero vista la solución del compañero Valle50, una solución podría ser esta. Aún así me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de hacerlo con los métodos de lso arrays, sobretodo con .map

Comment: @A.Baes actualicé la respuesta usando la función `map()`, es lo que buscabas?

Answer (score 0):

Aquí una manera de hacerlo, primero se recorren todas las palabras del `array`, después se recorren las letras de cada palabra y finalmente se recorren las vocales para ir haciendo la comparación e ir obteniendo cada vocal de cada palabra en caso de que se encuentren y después imprimir el resultado.

**UPDATE**

De acuerdo a lo que el OP comenta, se agregó la misma funcionalidad pero usando la función `map()`.

```js
var a = ["average", "exceptional", "amazing"];
var vocales = ["a","e","i","o","u","á","é","í","ó","ú"];
var b = [];//almacena vocales encontradas en todas las palabras
var aux = "";//almacena solo vocales

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
    aux = "";
        for(var k = 0; k < a[i].length; k++)
        {
            for(var j = 0; j < vocales.length; j++)
            {
                if(a[i][k] == vocales[j])//si la letra de la palabra es igual a una vocal
                {
                    //console.log("Letra "+ vocales[j]+" encontrada en posicion " + k + " de "+ a[i]);
                    aux += a[i][k];
                }
            }
        }
    
    b.push(aux);//almacena vocales encontradas en todas las palabras
}
console.log("Ejemplo con for anidado:");
console.log(b);//imprime resultado

//==========Ejemplo con map==========
const map = Array.prototype.map

var result = a.map(function(palabra)
{
    var aux2 = "";
    var read_letras = map.call(palabra, letra => 
    {
         var read_vocales = vocales.map( vocal => 
         {
            if(letra == vocal)
            {
                aux2 += letra;
            }
        });
    });
    return aux2;
});
console.log("Ejemplo con Array.map:");
console.log(result);
```